# I got error in ASP.NET Treeview (Error: Click ok to generate correct pathes.)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, treeview

I get the following message in ASP.NET webforms treeview.

> [Click ok to generate correct pathes.Treeview will work fine with
> correct pathes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNZ4V.png)

do anybody have an idea why this is happining.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show you code so it will be easier for others to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Connell.O'Donnell but I think no body is interested in reding over 500 line of code to findout the problem. all what I need is just a brief description about the mentioned error message.

Comment: Just show the treeview markup. And is this built-in control or a third-party?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.